# issue with Microsoft Japanese input

Tags: discussion, learning

I am trying to 仕送り (しおくり) after the word, 送る, somehow the computer thinks し and おくり are separate words, and I get 詩送り. But if I type しおくり in a new line, I would get the correct 仕送り.

How can I get the computer to separate/combine words?

Comment: what does it meaning "migrated from Japanese.stackexchange.com"?

Comment: Technically, this question is off-topic for JLU, which is about the Japanese language itself.  However, we've allowed some limited questions like these on the Meta site, so instead of closing the question, I moved it here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Japanese IME Tip #10: Shifting the parsing range](http://nihonshock.com/2010/04/12-japanese-ime-tips/) (on nihonshock.com).

Basically, you can press shift-left and shift-right to change how the parser chunks your input.  In this case, you want to hit **shift-right** a few times.  That should change it from し + おくり to しお + くり, then しおく + り and finally しおくり.

Comment: Wow. After using an IME for years I've never known this. That would have been so useful so many times.

Comment: same here. Very useful post.